# Modifying an existing calculated fields formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of calculated fields in an excel 2010 dashboard template that gets a #name error when data is initially entered into the pivot table.

```
'This is the calculated field 'Field1'
=100-('#NAME?'/'#NAME?')*100
```

To circumvent this I want to modify the formula in those fields when I first populate the data but I can't find anything outside of deleting and adding it again which I want to avoid.

I've tried recording myself modifying it but for some reason it doesn't update when added to my routine. For reference the section of code I've put this in is below and works fine ('Details' is a collection) but it does still not update the calculated field for some reason.

```
Workbooks(WB_Name).Worksheets("Total").Range("A" & Last_Row).Resize(UBound(Details), 47).Value = Details

'"Total" is the sheet where the source data is kept while "Stats" is where 
'the pivot tables are. I've chosen PT1 for no particular reason but there are
'about 5 others.

WB_Name.Worksheets("Stats").PivotTables("PivotTable1").CalculatedFields("Field1").StandardFormula = _
"=100-(Field2/Measured)*100"
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

By manually changing this in excel to the correct formula everything populates correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for a brief update it seems all I needed to do was modify the calculated field *after* I had refreshed the pivots. I'm assuming it wasn't working because it hadn't actually broken yet...

On the upside there is now an answer on how to modify a calculated field in excel!

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Stats").PivotTables("PivotTable1").CalculatedFields("Field1") _
.StandardFormula ="=100-(Field2/Measured)*100"
```